# Can cd into folder but I can't see it with ls or ls -a?

Tags: command-line, vmware, hidden-files

I've a shared partition between Windows and Ubuntu, achieved through VMWare's shared folders, and when I moved a folder into this shared folder Ubuntu couldn't see it.  Ubuntu still can't see it, but it can access it from the terminal.  It can access it from the terminal but cannot list the files with `ls` or `ls -a`.  The screenshot linked below demonstrates the issue.

[image]

Despite this, any files that Ubuntu puts in the folder are entirely visible by Windows.

How can I further debug the problem?

The output from ls -l /mnt/hgfs/F is:

```
calem@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/F$ ls -l /mnt/hgfs/F
ls: cannot access /mnt/hgfs/F/Screenshot from 2014-01-21 10^%42^%49.png: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /mnt/hgfs/F/System Volume Information: Permission denied
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan 20 16:54 GitHub
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jan 21 00:00 School
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? Screenshot from 2014-01-21 10^%42^%49.png
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? System Volume Information
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan 20 22:19 Virtual Machines
```

Note the screen shot png is the linked screen shot that I put in there from Ubuntu after posting the initial question (it's the shot used in this post).

Comment: thank you @Avinash!!  I couldn't add the picture because it's my first post here. :-/

Comment: we are here to help the new comers.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l /mnt/hgfs/F` to your question.

Comment: the output of ls -l /mnt/hgfs/F has been added

Comment: Has this problem being solved? If yes, please consider writing a answer for future users help.

Comment: No, sadly.
I decided to remove Ubuntu from my laptop entirely.
I later got a desktop and installed Debian on it, so a lot of the problems I was having don't apply to me anymore.

Comment: When you can't `ls` in a directory if you don't have read permissions on that specific folder. Run `chmod g+r path/of/folder` to give owning group read permissions. Use `chmod a+r path/of/folder` to give owning user read permissions.